# How to stop testing in a single file after first failure?

Tags: perl, testing

I'm using the `Test::More` module. If I have a `.t` file with a bunch of tests (mainly using `ok()`), how can I make the testcase stop after the first failure?

What I'm seeing right now is if the first `ok` fails, the subsequent `ok()` cases are still being run.

I looked at using `Test::More::Bail_OUT;`, but that will stop all testing to stop (meaning other `.t` files I have) rather than just testing to stop for the particular file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call `done_testing()` and `exit`.

```
ok( first_test(), 'first test' ) or done_testing, exit;
ok( second_test(), 'second test' );
...
```

In other cases, you can use the `skip` function inside a block with a `SKIP` label.

```
SKIP: {
    ok( first_test ) or skip "useless to run the next 4 tests", 4;
    ok( second_test );
    ok( third_test );
    ok( fourth_test );
    ok( fifth_test );
}
ok( sixth_test );
done_testing();
```

The main advantage of `skip/SKIP` is that it is supported in older versions of `Test::More`.

Comment: The main advantage of `skip` is that it doesn't claim that only the last test is failing.

Answer (score 11):

The [Test::More](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test/More.html) POD mentions [Test::Most](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::Most) for better control.  Perhaps `die_on_fail` does what you need.